# No puedo resolver el "Gradle project sync failed" y me da otro error que adjunto

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Por una parte me sale el error "Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host", leí que reiniciando android se componía pero me sigue saliendo el error. Por otra parte me sale:

> "Gradle project sync failed"

, ya intente varias opciones como ir a: "Sync project with gradle files", también descargue un gradle de internet e intente sincronizarlo desde android pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema indica que no puedes sincronizar la configuración definida en el archivo `build.gradle` con tu proyecto.

> "Gradle project sync failed"

esto puede deberse a varios factores, pero en este caso el mensaje define el problema

> "Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo
> host"

Indica que al tratar de descargar las dependencias definidas en el archivo `build.gradle` ocurrió un error en la conexión.

Revisa dos cosas:

• Te sugiero revisar tu conexión a internet o credenciales si estas bajo un proxy.
• Asegura no tengas activado el "modo offline":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]